# Adding vibration functionality for local notification in case App has been in background

Tags: notifications, local, iphone-vibrate

refer below links in case helpful.
[Add vibration the background for local notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627984/add-vibration-the-background-for-local-notifications)
[Unable to Handle Local Notification when app has been terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900876/unable-to-handle-local-notification-when-app-has-been-terminated)